# Broadcom brcm80211 installation from source

Tags: broadcom

Hello need help to get my wifi chipset working.I have brcmsmac driver and i would like to have brcm80211 chipset up and running. I have tried everything but nothing helped?

1. `git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/dwmw2/linux-firmware.git`
2. `Copy brcm/bcm43xx-0.fw and brcm/bcm43xx_hdr-0.fw to /lib/firmware/brcm (or wherever firmware is normally installed on your system).`

   still got brcmsmac ??

then i tryed

1. `git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git
   git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/dwmw2/linux-firmware.git`
2. `cd ~/linux-next/drivers/staging/brcm80211
   nano Makefile`

the problem is that there is no brcm82011 folder?? do i follow cd ~/linux-next-a694cb1 like the link sad? i have Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 [14e4:4727]

Comment: I clearly mentioned in my previous answer that wl driver supports ad-hoc and managed mode only. For monitor mode you can use brcmsmac driver.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10107880

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of doing this much stuff. with brcmsmac your wifi should work fine but it only supports managed and monitor mode. There is no support for ad-hoc, access point and bridges yet. So a better option is use a "wl0" driver which supports managed and ad-hoc modes plus bridges and works much better. Procedure for installation:

1. `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

   or
   you can install it from synaptic manager also, make sure `broadcom-sta-common`, `broadcom-sta-source`, `firmware-b43*` are **NOT INSTALLED**.
2. Even if you install the wl0 driver it won't load automatically as it is blacklisted by default. So make sure `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf` file looks like this:

   ```
   \# Warning: This file is autogenerated by bcmwl. All changes to this file will be lost.
   blacklist b43
   blacklist b43legacy
   blacklist ssb
   \#blacklist bcm43xx
   \#blacklist brcm80211
   blacklist brcmsmac
   blacklist bcma
   ```
3. If you wish you can copy above contents in your `blacklist-bcm43.conf` file.
4. Hope this works, best of luck! and make sure you restart your pc.

Comment: now i got wl driver but my chipset still unknown, and now i cant get my card in to monitor mode? damn

Comment: i had brcm80211 before, cuz im working with aircrack and i cant get  ignore negative one patch to work if i dont have brcm80211

Comment: and wl driver in not good

Answer (score 0):

all I did is,

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```