# Driver / Module brcm80211 missing

Tags: wireless, broadcom, acer

I'm user of Xubuntu 12.04 on an AOD270 Netbook.

It has a built-in chipset for the wifi connection Broadcom 4313 14a4:4727, which I'm trying to get to work in both normal and monitor mode.

I got it to work at once, but with a bug (the channel fixed on -1).
 While I was searching for the fix trying different solutions, It stopped working.
 So, bottom line, I had the chipset working with the right driver - but with a bug - I broke it; and now I'm trying to get all working again.

When I'm trying to load module brcm80211; with the following command:

```
sudo modprobe brcm80211
```

The terminal retrieves this message:

```
FATAL: Module brcm80211 not found.
```

I fear I deleted the module while trying to fix the -1 bug.

How can I fix this?

`lspci` and `lsmod` information are attached next.

http://pastebin.com/zfYx17dD

http://pastebin.com/yafbURZW

I have already read [Broadcom brcm80211 installation from source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102181/broadcom-brcm80211-installation-from-source)

Comment: Try the answers to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx

Comment: Thanks, I read it. I found I was missing some dependecies. After install, I will give a report.